# I need 6 nameservers but my registrar only allows me to input 5, what can I do to bypass this?

Tags: dns, netlify, nameservers

I bought a gen.xyz domain. Under manage nameservers there are only options for 5 nameservers.

I used 2 name servers to create a proxy with cloudflare (through workers routes). Now I want to put my domain on a netlify website I made, but netlify required 4 nameservers. This leaves me needing 6 but I only have the option to input 5. Is there anything I can do?

I looked if I could try it with three of netlify's name servers but it doesnt seem like it's allowed.

Comment: From the dns tag: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot point the same domain to multiple DNS hosts at the same time. The DNS Zone must be delegated to a single provider, either Cloudflare or Netlify.

Once you've delegated the domain to Cloudflare, you can use external DNS to point to Netlify: https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/. Make sure, you disable Cloudflare proxying (orange cloud).

Also, since you're asking about Netlify DNS, I'm assuming you've already set up an invalid DNS Zone on Netlify. Please delete the DNS Zone from Account Home > Domains.

Lastly, beware of these issues when using Cloudflare in front of Netlify:

https://answers.netlify.com/t/138
https://answers.netlify.com/t/8869